# JavaFX: How to change content CSS properties in ComboBox for text?

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox

The problem is that when you first click on the combobox, the text in it is displayed with a downward shift, but with further manipulations everything is fine. Moreover, if the cell has already been clicked previously, when clicked again, everything is fine too. Please tell me what could be the problem? [my problem in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7fxZ.png)

The dropdown list is in a table cell, but judging by the dropdown arrow, it is positioned correctly in the cell.

```
.table-view .cell .text-field,
.cell .combo-box,
.cell .text-field:hover,
.cell .combo-box:hover,
.cell .text-field:focused,
.cell .combo-box:focused{
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-content-display: center;
}

.table-view .cell .combo-box .list-view{
    -fx-background-color: -primary-color;
    -fx-translate-y: 10px;
}
.table-view .cell .combo-box > .cell{
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a rule that says `-fx-translate-y: 10px;`.  That seems strange to me.

Comment: this rule only shifts the drop-down list, it does not affect the cell itself in the combobox

Comment: Is this ComboBox in a TableView cell?

Comment: Create and post a [mre]